# Cannot enter address in App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

App Store Connect now ask for address in bank info, but when I type in the address, I got this:

```
This address has been modified. Verify the changes and resubmit.
```

What does this mean? I have tried to edit/submit many times and it is the same issue. Does other developers have similar issue?

PS: I get it to work now! The solution is stupid - tap "Save" 3 times, ignoring the error message.

Answer (score 40):

I get it to work now!

The solution is stupid - tap "Save" 3 times, ignoring the error message.

Comment: I confirm, this is really stupid but it works at the end..  Thanks!

Comment: OMG, why does this work?! Thanks anyways

Comment: Incredible....important thing is to not change anything between the clicks lol..for me it worked after two clicks!

Comment: Still "works" this way. Nov 28, 2022 ‍♂️

Comment: Still "works" this way. Mar 12, 2023. I can not beleave it!

Comment: For paid apps agreement, It worked for me. Apr 3 , 2023

Comment: Still "works" this way. May 18th 2023.

Comment: Still like this. Another great and innovative move by Apple

Comment: OMG this is still working 9th Feb 2024 :)

Comment: best engineers in the world everyone

Comment: It works ️, I can't belive it

Comment: That worked :D how the apple is working.

Answer (score 2):

When I entered "Aggrements, Tax and Banking" -> "Banking" and tried to add an address there, I got the same message as you did.

It only worked when I entered "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" -> "Agreements." I clicked "Paid Apps". Under "Bank accounts" I chose "Edit" -> "Edit Current Account" next to my account and filled in the address there. When I clicked "Save" I got the message "This address has been modified. Verify the changes and resubmit.", but this time the "State or Province" field was added. I clicked "Save" again and it saved without errors.

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough workaround! It didn't, however, work for me — I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work for me. I saw the "State or Province", whether to fill in or leave blank (I live in Singapore, there is no "State or Province"), the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

When I wanted to accept the paid apps agreement, they asked for my address. When I entered it, it gave me the error: "The address you submitted couldn't be verified. Review the address and edit if needed". I followed the advice of clicking "add" three times. After four clicks the error did not go away, then I edited my address (adding my city name again in the second address field) and then it accepted it.
The final address entered didn't work for me before. I guess it just needed 5 clicks to work.

Answer (score 0):

Dutch Address: Added the house suffix on the second line. For example:

Line1: Hondenweg 3A1

Should be:

Line1: Hondenweg 3
Line2: A1

From there, the platform will "standardize" your address. It will recognize. But it won't go through the first time. Hit the button at least four times, and you're good to go.

Bizarre